# How many bytes of the last keystream block are used to XOR the final block of partial plaintext in CFB, OFB & CTR modes?

Tags: aes, ctr, cfb, ofb

I apologize if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to understand how the final block of partial plaintext is XORed using only **n** number of bytes in the final keystream block.

How do we determine the number of bytes in the keystream that are required to produce a final block of the same size (128 bit) as the others?

Comment: They can all handle any number of bits.  Why do you have a concept of a block of partial plaintext here?  Are you using a padding scheme, not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Hi @SqueamishOssifrage I was reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Padding) and it says "The last partial block of plaintext is XORed with the first few bytes of the last keystream block, producing a final ciphertext block that is the same size as the final partial plaintext block." and I'm looking for a more in-depth explanation of how this works.

Comment: You just take as many bits as you need?  For, _e.g._, AES-CTR to encrypt an 87-bit message, you use AES to generate a 128-bit block and then take the first 87 bits to xor with your plaintext, and discard the remaining 41.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a block is $b$ bits long, say $b = 128$, and the message is $\ell$ bits long, say $\ell = 187$.  Then the final plaintext block is $n = \ell - \lfloor\ell/b\rfloor \cdot b$ bits long.  So use $n$ bits of the final keystream block; in this example, $n = 59$.